# Wingpanel Suddenly Disappeared

Tags: wingpanel

Since I'm a rookie, I don't know if it's because something I did but my top bar/wingpanel disappeared. When I type wingpanel on terminal, I get following text;

```
(wingpanel:2526): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:69: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(wingpanel:2526): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:71: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
[INFO 19:09:15.441220] Application.vala:155: Sistem Paneli version: 2.0.1
[INFO 19:09:15.441255] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 4.4.0-47-generic
[FATAL 19:09:15.496907] wingpanel_widgets_overlay_icon_set_main_icon_name: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[FATAL 19:09:15.497230] wingpanel_widgets_overlay_icon_set_main_icon_name: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[16:09:15.574393 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_file_get_child: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
[16:09:15.574414 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_file_query_exists: assertion 'G_IS_FILE(file)' failed
[16:09:15.574417 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_file_get_child: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
[16:09:15.574420 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_file_query_exists: assertion 'G_IS_FILE(file)' failed
[16:09:15.574424 Critical] gee_abstract_collection_get_size: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[16:09:15.574430 Warning] Theme.vala:508: Currently selected gtk+ theme 'elementary' does not provide a dock theme, fallback to the built-in defaults!
[16:09:15.847607 GLib-Critical] g_hash_table_get_keys: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
[16:09:15.862371 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_app_info_get_name: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed
[16:09:15.862801 GLib-GIO-Critical] g_app_info_get_id: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've searched everywhere, tried everything I found, but useless. And I don't know how to fallback to the built-in defaults.

Hope someone can help me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone having this issue, I solved the problem with resetting of desktop configurations to do defaults as it said in the warning. To do so, run the following in the terminal;

cd $HOME
cd .config
rm -R *

and then to reboot your system to changes take effect, simply run this;

reboot

This will solve the problem and the wingpanel will come back. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

OPTION 1: open a terminal window from the dock (plank) and start wingpanel with `wingpanel &`. The & at the end allows the process to keep running when the terminal is closed.

OPTION 2: if you cannot open a terminal window go to tty6 (or 1-5) by typing `Ctrl+Alt+F6` and loging with your username and password, then type `DISPLAY=:0 wingpanel &` and go back to your GUI (tty7: `Ctrl+Alt+F7`).

If `ps -ef | grep wingpanel` is showing multiple wingpanel processes running, you may want to stop them all before restarting wingpanel with the beforementioned options: `killall wingpanel`.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a logitech wireless mouse or keyboard?

if so,  Does unplugging the wireless receiver bring back the wingpanel?

If yes, Then you need to uninstall the wingpanel with:

```
sudo apt-get remove wingpanel-indicator-power
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - wingpanel suddenly disappeared.

Did a "ps -ef | grep wingpanel" in terminal and realized wingpanel wasn't running.

Restarted wingpanel process by typing "wingpanel" in terminal and wingpanel reappeared. That's it!