# Missing the top panel. how to return the panel?

Tags: wingpanel

when entering commands "wingpanel" here is a log appears. 
[image: window error]

Comment: I'm not an expert at this but I would try to reboot, and then if that doesn't solve the issue, then I would just `sudo apt-get purge wingpanel` and `sudo apt-get install wingpanel` again.

Comment: There's also a similar question with an answer. Try to see if that works for you.
http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9251/wingpanel-suddenly-disappeared

Comment: at reboot, the system does not start when you enter the password writes "failed to start session"

Comment: what do I do, I do not start a session when you enter a password

Comment: After the command is on top

Comment: no idea. You might have to reinstall the OS again.

Answer (score 2):

Use `killall wingpanel` in terminal - it should reset the wingpanel and bring it after few seconds. ;)

It happens from time to time.

Comment: Where were you before :)

Comment: Finding out how to restart my wingpanel  ;)

Answer (score -2):

The wingpannel once dissapeared on me too To fix this, run this command in the terminal. (does not have to be root)

```
cd $HOME cd .config rm -R *
```

Then run this to restart the computer.

```
reboot
```

When you log back in, it should be back to normal.

Tip: if you don't have a terminal in your dock, dont panic! you can always open a full terminal by pushing **ctrl + alt + f1**. You can go back to the desktop by pushing **ctrl + alt + f7**. Just remember these things:

- When logging in, use the nickname that you chose when installing.
- be careful with what you do. The terminal is a great way to ruin your system
- Always remember to use the command "exit" without the quotes to log back out. Failure to do this will result in the shell being open to anyone who passes by your computer.

Comment: I believe that you don't need to restart your whole system to solve it :)

And hey! Terminal is a great way to learn something about system work and how to work with CLI based systems - don't scare our friend ;)

Comment: Do **not** `rm` your whole `.config` directory! That will delete settings from a lot of applications!